# "Не" с причастиями (1)

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно, причастия

В тренировочном тексте ЕГЭ по русскому языку читаем:
*Трагедия, однако, в том, что у громадного, подавляющего большинства детей это начало остаётся **не увиденным**, **не поддержанным**, а значит, **не реализованным***.

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему выделенные причастия в тексте написаны с **не** раздельно?
Ведь по правилам полное причастие, если нет зависимого слова и противопоставления, пишется слитно.

Answer (score 2):

Трагедия, однако, в том, что у громадного, подавляющего большинства детей это начало остаётся **не увиденным, не поддержанным, а значит, не реализованным.**

В конструкциях такого рода, когда одиночное причастие входит в состав сказуемого, возможен  выбор: **отрицание** признака  или **утверждение** противоположного признака (неувиденный ― скрытый).

Примеры

1) Легкий щелчок. Бриллиант на моей шее остается **неувиденным.** Да и бриллиант чужой. [Виктория Токарева. Мой мастер (1964-1994)]

Многое мы увидели и узнали за свою экспедицию, многое еще **осталось неувиденным**... [И. Семенов. «Лев Берг» выходит в море // «Спортсмен-подводник», 1965]

2) Спустя десятилетие главный фильм Эфроса **остается практически не увиденным**; его высказывание ― **не расслышанным или непонятым.** [Михаил Гуревич. Пространство и время человеческого существования (1990-2000)]

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Согласно формАльным правилам, с полными формами причастий НЕ пишется слитно:
а) при отсутствии зависимых слов, напр.: невооружённые солдаты.
б) в составе конструкций, подчеркивающих утверждение  напр.: весьма необдуманный поступок.

Но не во всех случаях задача решается формально, например в ПАС дается такая информация: http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=79#pp79

"Таким образом, **пишущий должен отдавать себе отчет в том, что он хочет выразить: отрицание признака** — и тогда написать не отдельно от следующего слова (напр.: он не здоров, не важно, не редки случаи, не случайно, не существенно, не удивительно, не демократическим путём) **или утверждение признака — и тогда написать не слитно** (ср.: он нездоров, нередки случаи, неважно, неслучайно, несущественно, неудивительно, недемократическим путем). От выбора написания будет зависеть и понимание написанного читающими".

**Приведенное правило касается прилагательных,** но полные причастия без зависимых слов, с одной стороны, близки  к ним по значению, а с другой стороны,  у них даже больше шансов для раздельного написания НЕ, так как они выражают признак по действию, а в приведенных конструкциях еще и выполняют функцию сказуемого.

**Еще примеры с раздельным написанием:**

Но он до сих пор остаётся **не принятым.**

Остается **не выясненным** вопрос об основном природном носителе вируса.

Однако вопрос о границах рода и числе относящихся к нему видов пока остается **не решенным.**

При этом режущая часть меча остается **не закрытой.**

С 1 июля до этого срока статус арбитражного управляющего остается **не регламентированным.**

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не знала о таком правиле (отрицание признака или утверждение противоположного признака по отношению к причастиям). Не могли бы Вы дать ссылку? Не получается применить это правило к моему предложению. Да и к Вашим примерам тоже. В предложении про фильм Эфроса не увиденный пишется раздельно из-за зависимого слова практически, а вот слово нерасслышанный я бы написала слитно.

Comment: Посмотрите дополнение в ответе.